# Flow type refinement to ensure it is not a React Node

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have one function that takes a sum type which includes React Node as one of the possible values.
I can fix almost all flow errors by narrowing down types and saving values on variables, but I can't find a way to tell flow that I already checked that the variable is not a React Node. I used `React.isValidElement` to narrow it down, but flow still complains that certain properties are missing on Iterable, or String, or any of the many possible values of React Node.
How can I make flow understand that I already checked for that and that we are safe to continue?

Here is some example code:

```js
/* @flow */
import type {Node} from 'react'
import { isValidElement } from 'react'

type Error = {|
  message: string,
  variables?: Object,
|}

export type MaybeError =  Error | Node | void

const getErrorTranslation = (error: MaybeError) => {
  if (isValidElement(error) || !error) return error
  const { message, variables } = error
  if (!message ) return error
  const segments = message.split('.')
  // bla bla bla, code
  const defaultValue = message
  if (variables) return variables
  return message
}
```

and here is a link to [flow playground](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuYBAntgKZgDeAcnACbkC+YUecmYA5HuQIYBjAlww58RKmHQBnAGp8Y6egFEY5TOQB2RFmw7deg4alSkKYZXnZ4wAXmoAfVGDAbp0vgHNyALjDSCPHRNTwAaZzAANz4gvgAjNWkAfj8AeTiAK3IhcIcmE3IAD1xCYjJKAFk+EjjyS2s7F3r8MAcwOkZWqLglEwE4TQCwbwJmvAAVPD5BmD4CdAHGgApyK3w-Kpq6tbwASjsAPmoI9CgwJZl5RRU1DW0Vnf2HNoBCVet93gIAVzxNMHe+Ai-UGElc5HcXnIoSiMXQ8USYBY9kBeBOZyWLzcHm8YE+5B+fwBO2BAyG0nInjuBGkjWxUIAdNJsIoCEsuAyuLsIsBgGAEnx+bMhXwYf1GKTQWBGFA+N8YAQrt9KPZ6d50edorEEhD8YT-lr4TrpBEvr9-mryKgmEA)

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6392